# Akeeba backup Joomla 2.5.14 & cpanel all files unwriteable

Tags: joomla2.5, file-permissions

I uploaded a website that is working in the localhost using Akeeba backup. It is done by creating a new public_html at the host using its cpanel. Next i transfer the .jpa & the kickstart.php to this new folder. Finally i browse the kickstart.php and restore the website running on joomla 2.5.14.

Accessing the admin panel of Joomla, it reports all folders as WRITEABLE and site runs good. In cpanel all folders permission is set to 755 & files 644 as expected; i then change configuration.php to 444.

However when i try to edit the configuration.php in the host, i found i can't change the file permission or save any edit. This in fact affects all files. After informing the host, they change the file ownership setting, then in cpanel i CAN edit files BUT now Joomla reports all folders become UNWRITEABLE creating more problems eg cannot install new extension; some how Joomla no longer has edit rights to the folders.

More ... at this state, to make a folder WRITEABLE to Joomla, it must be set file permission to 777. It is unexpected & unacceptable; 775 is sufficient for Joomla to report as writeable ie if the host is doing the right thing for Joomla (as i found in another hosting site).

When i tell the host to change it back to the state after Akeeba restoration, they say that will mean they have to set the folders with ownership = nobody.

I would imagine ownership of folders & all its content can be made to be the cpanel user AND the joomla ie php/apache user. Can someone enlighten me this puzzle so that i can talk more intelligently with the host or point where i went wrong. I am getting no where with them.

PS: Latest Sharing Update

The solution is find a host that has Server API showing as cgi/fastcgi which mean that suPHP of Apache is enabled (sorry cannot post .jpg < 10 reputation)

With cgi, Joomla report all 755 folders as writeable.

Now the new question
If the host use Server API = Apache 2.0, how can i enable suPHP from the website?

Answer (score 0):

As you have worked out, suPHP or FastCGI should usually be enabled for Joomla file permissions and file ownership to work as you would expect.

There is a good article on this at: http://boomshadow.net/tech/php-handlers

In a shared hosting environment you don't usually have access to change which PHP file handler is enabled but your web hosting company may be able to change this for you.

If your web hosting company can't enable suPHP or FastCGI, the only other option might be to find a new web hosting company.